# CSS loaded dynamically from jQuery plugin - CSS must be loaded because it's required for the function

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I have created a jQuery plugin for a navigation menu.  Within JavaScript, in the jQuery plugin JavaScript file (at the top of the file) I am dynamically loading CSS related to the plugin. Then in `$(document).ready(function()` I am attaching the plugin to an HTML element, a DIV.

The problem is that when the plugin starts up, it calculates some outerWidth()s based on the CSS that is applied to the elements. In some browsers, the plugin is executing before the CSS has been fully loaded and applied to the HTML. When this occurs, the width calculations are incorrect. Often, it is getting the width of the window instead of getting it from an li or ul element.

I have code like the following in the plugin JavaScript file:

```
function includeCSS(p_file) {
    var v_css = document.createElement('link');
    v_css.rel = 'stylesheet'
    v_css.type = 'text/css';
    v_css.href = p_file;        
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(v_css);
}

includeCSS("Scripts/jQuery/plugins/jquery-mmm-1.0/menu.css");
```

I have tried loading the css in the jQuery init method but this too has similar issues.

I need to specify the CSS from within the jQuery plugin JavaScript file (to keep things easy for the end user).

While working through this, I directly linked to the CSS in the HTML page. While doing this, things worked great. The problem is definitely that when I dynamically load the CSS and subsequently require this CSS to be applied for calculations from the plugin.

How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

Most plugins give the developer instructions to include both the CSS and the JavaScript in the head section. Most web developers who are familiar with jQuery are used to this convention. Not only does it work well, but there are less conflicts between other JavaScript, CSS, and HTML validation issues that should be expected in the wild. While professional developers with experience might take the time to validate their code and architect their sites in a thoughtful manner, the Internet community as a whole is quite diverse, and many do not always adhere to these principles.

With that said, you could download the CSS as text/plain content using an AJAX request, and then in your success handler, add the CSS to a `<style>` block and then invoke your width-calculating functions:

**Solution using AJAX to Retrieve CSS:**

Make sure that the CSS loads before any JavaScript runs by loading the CSS into a JavaScript string and then building a `<style>` element dynamically.

```
$.ajax({ "url" : "/css/yourstyle.css",
    success: function(data) {
        // assume data is "body { background-color:yellow; }";
        $('head').append('<style id="testtest"></style>');
        $('head').find("#testtest").html( cssString );

        // now fire your width-calculating function here
    }
});
```

One problem with this approach may include styles not rendering properly because of their order of operations. In general, inline styles are given higher priority than style blocks, and style blocks are given higher priority than external stylesheets. Since your CSS is now loaded as a style block instead of an external stylesheet, it may override or otherwise invalidate styles that you didn't intend to override.

This could force your users to have to modify their CSS to include more specific CSS rules or use the !important identifier in CSS rules.

Also, make sure it's easy for the developer to reconfigure the location of the CSS file. Your path is relative, and if I have HTML files in different folders, they may not be able to find your CSS file.

In summary, this approach can work quite well, but you should be prepared to put more time and maintenance into such a solution and to handle differences in how the CSS may be  interpreted.  Good luck! :)

Comment: jeeee, Just felt like a small ant by reading this answer! +'d this, Nice broad explanation! :)

Comment: @Zuul - Thanks for the feedback. I did just revise the last sentence in the first paragraph as it seemed kind of arrogant after I read it again. ;)

Comment: That is an improvement yes, but I REALLY did felt like a tiny "ant" near your answer! Great work indeed! :)

Comment: @Zuul - I try my best to be thorough :)  But you shouldn't feel like a small ant. I +'d your answer because it's 100% correct and solid.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve that issue is to load the `CSS` with [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and call the remaining of your code when that operation is completed!

**JQUERY**

```
var css = "foobar.css";
var callback = function() {
  alert("CSS is now included");
  // your jquery plugin for a navigation menu
};

$.get(css, function(data){
  $("<style type=\"text/css\">" + data + "</style>").appendTo(document.head);
  callback();
});
```